# The type or namespace name 'Dialogs' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder'

Tags: c#, azure, chat, bots, azure-qna-maker

I'm building a chat bot with Microsoft Azure on .NET Framework C#, installed all the references, but after update to `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` 4.0.7 this reference is unable to find it and showing this type of error:

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Dialogs' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am guessing you are missing an assembly reference

Comment: and what's that assembly reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, they got problem with .net standard and latest bot-package update. Use **stable bot-package version 3.15.2**, no need to update all, just update other things except bot related reference. The Problem is going to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific package for the Dialogs which is does not come with `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` even though it is the same namespace. You need to install the package `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs` linked [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/) and add that to your using statements. That ought to get rid of your error.

Using Package Manager
`Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs`

Using .NET CLI (for dotnet core)
`dotnet add package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs`

Comment: thanks @michael-dera, but that issue was solved back on 2018.

Comment: That's alright @DibyajitGoswami.. I assumed it had not cause nothing had been accepted as a solution. 

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the google machine, i have figured you are probably jsut needing

[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/)

**Disclaimer** , after looking around for resources and documentation on this, i have managed to find none to show the available SDK nugets

Its like they want to keep it a secret

Comment: its not like that, I'm developing a chat bot which is having all the classes required for it from the Microsoft.Bot.Builder so it is not viable to use just that, though I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .NET framework version >=4.6. This error is faced when .net framework is 4.5. Microsoft.Bot.Builder version 3.8.0 works with it.